# Запуск приложения со скрытым окном

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

За отображение и скрытие отвечает свойство `Visibility`, но если его по умолчанию установить в `Hide` то форма на мгновение всё равно появится. Есть ли лишённый этого недостатка способ запустить приложение со скрытым окном?

Comment: `WindowState - minimized` попробуйте.

Comment: Это совсем не то. Я пробовал.

Comment: Можно просто не создавать экземпляр окна, в файле app.xaml.cs

Comment: Но мне нужно не навсегда его скрыть, а иметь возможность потом его показывать и скрывать повторно. Допустим по клику по иконке в system tray.

Comment: Аналогично, создаете и показываете окно, когда вам надо. `new Window().Show()`

Comment: Проверил. Если не создавать экземпляр окна, то и иконка в system tray не создаётся. А мне собственно нужно чтобы при клике по ней окно начинало отображаться.

Comment: Почему нет? Создавайте иконку не в окне, только и всего.